# How do you make sure that Vimeo video exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo, vimeo-api

So, I'm trying to show a Vimeo video only if it exist. I'm using new JavaScript API.

As per their [documentation](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#error), `error` event should get triggered when a video face errors while loading. I believe, adding a wrong Vimeo video URL should also trigger the `error` event.

This is what I did to get the `error` event in action:

```
<iframe id="vimeo-player1" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/13333693532?autoplay=0&amp;background=1" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

**Approach 1**

```
player = new Vimeo.Player($('#vimeo-player1'));

player.on('error', function() {
    console.log('Error in loading video');
});
```

**Approach 2**

```
player = new Vimeo.Player($('#vimeo-player1'));

player.loadVideo().then(function(id) {
    console.log('loaded');
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

None of them working. It never executed the error block.

**Some Additional Information (To help you to win Bounty):**

- Client side solution is required (I don't have access to the server side of the portal)
- Videos are hosted by third party users

Comment: Vimeo will set a data-attr to the iframe (data-ready not really reliable - I think in fact of cache) but may you can play a bit around: [here a fiddle](http://jsbin.com/xoyeluvuzi/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way that I found is to call the Vimeo API using the oEmbed open standard:

```
function checkIfVideoExists(url, callback){
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: 'https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
        dataType: 'json',
        complete: function(xhr) {
            callback(xhr.status);
        } 
    });
}

checkIfVideoExists("https://vimeo.com/217775903", function(status){
    console.log(status); // 200 - OK
});

checkIfVideoExists("https://vimeo.com/234242343", function(status){
    console.log(status); // 404 - Not found
});
```

[Live example](https://jsfiddle.net/suap2jkc/5/) on jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

***note: running the code locally or on jsbin.com works fine but not here, not sure why.***

Building upon what MarcelD said :

```js
var element1 = document.querySelector('#player1');
var element2 = document.querySelector('#player2');

var player1 = new Vimeo.Player(element1);
var player2 = new Vimeo.Player(element2);

element1.onload = function (data) { onLoad(data, 1) }
element2.onload = function (data) { onLoad(data, 2) }

function onLoad(data, id) {
  if (data.target.dataset.ready === undefined) {
    alert("#" + id + " video does not exist");
    return;
  } 
  alert("#" + id + " it exists");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="player1" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/215101645556" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<iframe id="player2" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/215101646" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Mate. Logically it seems to be good. But, when I tested it locally it's giving "video does not exist" for both the video.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with http get method if source is exist.

Jquery get :

```
$.get( "https://player.vimeo.com/video/13333693532?autoplay=0&amp;background=1")
.done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response mate.. But due to CORS restriction it will always fall to fail block.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Vimeo API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/start), there is [videos endpoint](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/videos#GET/videos/%7Bvideo_id%7D) which is meets your need. Here is the sample of this action in [Vimeo Playground](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/videos/216658674)

But, unfortunately there isn't JS SDK yet, you can use [Server-Side SDK](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/libraries)'s before send page to browser and check video is exists or you need to deep dive and write your own implementation for client side and decide to show user video or not.